# How to execute SQL function in Azure function project

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

I am working on an azure function that is invoking a web service in node.js and it works fine. I have a function `GetDetails` to make an SQL query to retreive data from sql server database.

```
const sql = require("mssql");
const dataSQL = {};
const GUID = "";
const navServiceKey = "";
const navUserName = "";

async function GetDetails() {
 var email = "yamen@gmail.com";
 var password = "password";
try {
console.log("nav service" + navServiceKey);
// make sure that any items are correctly URL encoded in the connection string
await sql.connect(
  "Server=tcp:app.windows.net,1433;Database=BHUB_TEST;User Id=AppUser;Password=password;Encrypt=true MultipleActiveResultSets=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ConnectionTimeout=30;"
);
const result =
  await sql.query`select * from users where email = ${email} AND password = ${password} `;

if (result.rowsAffected[0] >= 1) {
  dataSQL = result.recordset[0];
  navServiceKey = JSON.stringify(dataSQL.navServiceKey);
  GUID = JSON.stringify(dataSQL.userGUID);
  navUserName = JSON.stringify(dataSQL.navUserName);
} else {
  console.log("failed");
}
} catch (err) {
}}
```

so since this is in node.js if i were to test this sql function only i'd do the following i.e. `node index.js` - then function will be executed successfully and return result. However, I am calling this function within the azure function like below but when I run the azure function project, then I copy the URL given to test it on postman, the sql function won't return anything !

Any idea of how to execute SQL query function in Azure function if that makes sense ?

```
 module.exports = async function (context, req) {
 GetDetails();
 const axios = require("axios");
 const data = {
 email: req.query.email,
 password: req.query.password,
}; 

 var cred = "YAMEN" + ":" + "jbdv******";
 const encoded = Buffer.from(cred, "utf8").toString("base64");
 var credbase64 = "Basic " + encoded;

const headers = {
Authorization: credbase64,
"Content-Type": " application/json",
};

{
try {
  const url = `https://tegos/BC19-NUP/QryEnwisAppUser?filter=UserSecurityID eq ${GUID}`;
  const response = await axios.get(url, {
    headers,
  });
  console.log(response);
  console.log(response.data);
  context.res = {
    // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
    body: response.data,
  };
} catch (e) {
  // maybe return the error
  console.error(e);
}}};
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you connect to a SQL database from an Azure application. You need to use the `pyodbc` module instead.

[Quickstart: Use Python to query a database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-python?view=azuresql)

Comment: just to clarify there that my database is held in Microsoft SQL Server, not in Azure SQL database

Comment: The ODBC driver supports that too. ODBC drivers are by default installed as part of the function environment

Comment: Is this only can be done in python !

Comment: You do not seem to fully understand the nature of serverless environments. You can only access modules that are loaded when your VM instance runs. This instance has some features or modules pre-installed. If you need to have other modules/features, you need to put them in a container (e.g Docker container) and deploy that container to the cloud. The default environment may or may not have the feature you want.